# Subseting data frame by another data frame

Tags: r

The data is as follows:

```
> x
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 3 a
4 1 b
5 2 b
6 3 b

> y
  a b
1 2 a
2 3 a
3 3 b
```

My goal is to compare both data frames, and for each row in `x` indicate whether equivalent row exists in `y`. All of the `y` rows are actually contained in `x`, so I would like to end up with something like this:

```
> x
  a b intersect.x.y
1 1 a             F
2 2 a             T
3 3 a             T
4 1 b             F
5 2 b             F
6 3 b             T
```

How about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
x$rn          <- 1:nrow(x)
xyrows        <- merge(x,y)$rn # maybe you just want to look at the merge ...?
x$iny         <- FALSE
x$iny[xyrows] <- TRUE
```

I suspect there is a more standard approach, but this way is easy to understand.

Comment: Excellent! And, the fastest answer on SO ever, too (to one of my questions, anyways). `merge` is indeed what I needed to look into.  Thank you, good sir, very handy.